# How to run a script on multiple sheets of Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I would like to run a countdown timer on specific tabs in my Google worksheet, but not necessarily all of the tabs "Sheet1" and "Sheet2". I have tried some method from other posts but it does not work in my case. I am just a beginner and looking for your help.
[countdowntimer][1]

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

function  countDownSeconds(seconds, minutes){
 while (minutes >=0){   
    sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(minutes);     
   while (seconds >= 0 ){     
     var m = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
     var s = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
     if (m === 'pausing' || s === 'pausing'|| m === 'reset' || s === 'reset' ) {
      return
     }      
     sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(seconds); 
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     Utilities.sleep(1000)
     seconds --
   }    
   seconds = 59;
   minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
   minutes --
 }
}

function startTimer(){
  var minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
  var seconds = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
  countDownSeconds(seconds, minutes)

}

function pause(){
  var minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
  var seconds = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue('pausing');  
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue('pausing');   
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(minutes)
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(seconds)
}

function reset(){
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue('reset');  
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue('reset');   
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(0)
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(0)
}


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnSIZ.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script.

As you are running the functions attached to a button, you can call the active sheet instead of calling the sheet by name.

```
function  countDownSeconds(seconds, minutes){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

 while (minutes >=0){   
    sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(minutes);     
   while (seconds >= 0 ){     
     var m = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
     var s = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
     if (m === 'pausing' || s === 'pausing'|| m === 'reset' || s === 'reset' ) {
      return
     }      
     sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(seconds); 
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     Utilities.sleep(1000)
     seconds --
   }    
   seconds = 59;
   minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();
   minutes --
 }
}

function startTimer(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
  var seconds = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
  countDownSeconds(seconds, minutes)

}

function pause(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var minutes = sheet.getRange(2,1).getValue()
  var seconds = sheet.getRange(2,2).getValue()
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue('pausing');  
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue('pausing');   
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(minutes)
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(seconds)
}

function reset(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue('reset');  
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue('reset');   
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(0)
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(0)
}
```

I made a sample sheet. See two tabls time1 and time2

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16XwVAF6DqIaREA9Cvxz2IvsON5vFJc0gJjHHPR9ZKH4/edit#gid=495629246

The buttons are working in both sheets

Comment: I have tried with your code but it still not work. I want to run a countdown timer for 2 sheet "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" separately.
[countdowntimer](https://ibb.co/BNHdg10)

Comment: I modified the script. I tested in a sheet. Please see the modified answer. Hope your issue is solved

Comment: You are generous! Thank you so much! It works perfectly to me.

Comment: If it helped you, pl. consider accepting the answer. It may help others